# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException) Exception

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-jdbc

i am trying to save record in my sql server database using spring when i try to run the application i am getting  **org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ClientConnectionId:1a7dc54d-3764-44ff-ab47-8793b826b093**

**Employee.java**

```
package com;

public class Employee {
private int id;
private String name;
private int salary;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public Employee() {

}
public Employee(int id, String name, int salary) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
}

}
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
package com;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class EmployeeDao {
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {  

    this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
}
public int saveEmployee(Employee e){  
    String query="insert into employee values('"+e.getId()+"','"+e.getName()+"','"+e.getSalary()+"')";  
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);  
}  
public int updateEmployee(Employee e){  
    String query="update employee set name='"+e.getName()+"',salary='"+e.getSalary()+"' where id='"+e.getId()+"' ";  
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);  
}  
public int deleteEmployee(Employee e){  
    String query="delete from employee where id='"+e.getId()+"' ";  
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);  
}  

}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource"/>
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:5432;databaseName=qm"/>
      <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
          <property name="password" value="mypass"/>           
</bean>  

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="edao" class="com.EmployeeDao">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean>  



</beans>
```

and my App Test is
**Test.java**

```
package com;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  

    EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)ctx.getBean("edao");  
    int status=dao.saveEmployee(new Employee(102,"Amit",35));  
    System.out.println(status);  
}
}
```

Comment: Check SQL server error log for some error. Maybe it expects encypted connection and your connection is not encrypted

Comment: how to check that can you late me know

Comment: Locate SQL SERVER error log and look there